# Using "mapply" with "bigmemory" in r

Tags: r, mapply, r-bigmemory

I have 3 very large vectors in R (one of principal payments, one of interest rates and one of terms). I need to pass every possible combination through a function (pmt function from the FinCal package). I put each vector into a big matrix (from the bigmemory package) but am unable to run mapply on the big matrices (receive "this S4 class is not subsettable"). The only slot in the big matrix is the pointer and I am unable to specify it with @. Is there any way to loop through a big matrix to perform a computation like this or any other suggestion? There's around 350 million combinations.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can see exactly what code you are running.

Comment: If a brute force approach gets unfeasible it's time to look for a smarter approach.

Comment: There currently isn't a binding for `mapply` with `big.matrix` objects.  You will need to create a for loop (preferably using `foreach` for parallelism) at the moment.  I will add it to our list of features to add.  Regarding your immediate question, you need to provide a reproducible question for us to provide a more immediate workaround solution.